# add a class to div if it contains a number

Tags: jquery

Ok, should be easy, can't figure out why it isn't working.

class called toggle_comments, using regex to scoop the number, if it's zero, add a class to it, simple?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $( ".toggle_comments" ).each(function() {
var xc = $(this).text().length;
    var matches = $(this).text().match(/^0$/);
    if (matches){
       $(this).attr('class', 'numb');    
    }
});

});
```

No worky.

Comment: use addClass("numb");

Comment: Please be more specific than "it isn't working". Also provide a **complete** example.

Comment: Instead of that match, why not `=== '0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the Regular Expression to this `/0+/g`.  That should fix your problem.

Comment: I don't think he wanted it to be *any* number, but only zero since he said "if it's zero, add a class to it" in the original post.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely read over that.  Thanks for the tip @fstanis

Comment: Think I've figured out the problem, here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4P9CC/3/  It works here, but not on my page, perhaps because I'm adding the elements that I want to run this function on with js.

Comment: Yeah, that was it^ When I moved it into the scope of the function that done that, it works just fine.